# Table Per Concrete Type in Entity Framework Core

Tags: database-design, entity-framework, orm, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm trying to port code from entity framework 6 (EF6) to entity framework core 2.0 (EF-Core) and have ran into a dead end.

In my EF6 code, I have a base class called `Record` which defines the base properties and methods of all `Record` types. This base class provides common functionality and properties for all different types of records.

There are many different types of records which derive from the base `Record` class. Each of these `Records` have additional properties specific to that type of record. For example, I have a `CustomerComplaint` class and `TrainingRecord` class which both derive from the `Record` class. As you may be able to guess, the two `Records` have very different properties; however, they both share common functionality such as editing, submitting, permission checking, etc.

My problem is that EF-Core does not support Table per Concrete type inheritance hierarchies (e.g., a separate table for each type of record). Currently, EF-Core [only supports mapping inheritance hierarchies to Table per Hierarchy schemes](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/inheritance) (e.g., a single table with the properties of all subclasses and a discriminator value to differentiate between the subclasses). Given that I have a dozen or so different types of records, a Table per Hierarchy scheme would result in a monstrosity of a table inside my database; it would create a single table with columns for all of the properties of all of my record subclasses!

How should I implement a workaround to this problem? One solution I thought of is to break the hierarchy apart into interfaces and services. I could share common properties by defining an interface with those properties, and I could share common code by moving the code into a service class that operates only on objects that implement my interface.

Answer (score 1):

While there of course could be far too many columns in a table, the main reason that this is a problem is when you try to handle all of them at the same time, which would be a problem if you write your own SQL-statements.

Entity Framework is actually quite good at handling Table-Per-Hierarchy, in your code you only see the columns actually used by the specific subclass. Therefore it is not as big a problem as it would be if the sql was written by hand. In your code it will seem as there are a different table for each subclass.

If the table is too big for you, then your own solution sounds good. And would be the way I would go about it.

I haven't tried it, but perhaps you can have each subclass inherit from the same baseclass, but not have a `DbSet<>` for that baseclass resulting in Entity Framework not using Table-Per-Hierarchy but seperate tables.

Comment: I tried turning the Record class into an abstract base class and then creating a DbSet<> for the concrete base classes, but EF-Core still turned this into a Table per Hierarchy scheme.